# search nearby places using google maps API URL gives Request Denied

Tags: objective-c, json, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

hi i want to find nearby places using current location.i went through many documentation and also logged in developer.google.com/console and created new project.In services i enabled google api services,but when i try to place this below link in the browzer https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=12.91136601187478,77.598882598177313&radius=5000@&types=bar@&sensor=true&key=MYkey

it gives

```
 {`"html_attributions" : [],``
   "results" : [],
  "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
```

}`

why this happens?? i am not able to find solution for this even though going through many documentation can anyone tel me the solution for this.

Comment: which services exactly you've enabled? For the request above it has to be the Places-API-service.

Comment: @Dr.Molle  yes i have enabled places API request and now i am getting invalid Request

Comment: remove the @-characters from the url

Answer (score 1):

Use Google nearBySearch.

There is example:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

On the link below you can find full spec. In your request you need to fill out all required parameters (location, radius, sensor and AppKey), otherwise you will get "REQUEST_DENIED"
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

Don't forget to turn on service "Places API" under developer console.